# AngularJs/ExpressJs: Best way to manage real time notifications

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using AngularJs on frontend and ExpressJs on backend and I would like to know the best way to manage real time notification.

I hesitate between using sockets(socket.io) or querying notifications every 5 seconds

What is the cleanest way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what socket.io is for.

You don't want to make unnessessary HTTP requests to query a notification endpoint every 5 seconds. Imagine this on a scale of 100 users. What about 1000 users?

socket.io lets you initiate communication on the server side without having to make a request from the client. Notify the client when the client needs to be notified.